# Can I use the same Ansible handler twice in one playbook execution?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create a file to denote that an execution of a script / command has been done

I know we should avoid script / command but here I cannot

So to prevent re-execution I am creating a file to denote it has already been executed

This works for the latter task but not the former!

I'm wondering if the same handler can be used twice or not

tasks ..

```
- set_fact: donefile=nodesource_setup

- name: Ensure node install script executed
  shell: ~/tmp/nodesource_setup.sh >> ~/tmp/nodesource_setup.log
  args:
    creates: ~/tmp/{{ donefile }}.done # Cannot one line this
  notify: Done

- set_fact: donefile=ensure-npm-does-not-use-unicode

- name: Ensure npm does not use unicode
  command: npm config set unicode false
  args:
    creates: ~/tmp/{{ donefile }}.done
  notify: Done
```

handlers ..

```
- name: Done
  copy:
    content: "done"
    dest: ~/tmp/{{ donefile }}.done
    force: no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A handler is a task that is run once:

- after all other tasks had been run (default)
- on `meta: flush_handlers` task (the "notify" flag is reset and if a handler is notified again it will be run again)

---

The problem with your code is that at the time of execution of the `Done` handler, your `donefile` variable will have the last value of `donefile=ensure-npm-does-not-use-unicode`.

---

You can add the task:

```
- meta: flush_handlers
```

before you change the value of `donefile`, so that for a given value the handlers will be run. The only problem is that it doesn't make much sense - it can be a regular task not a handler.

The raison d'etre of a handler is to prevent it from being executed more than once even though several tasks might request it.

If you want to run it once, you can just go with a regular task or a task with `when` condition.

Comment: - meta: flush_handlers .. is awesome thx, did exactly what i wanted. great insights. i prefer handlers for trivial notification tasks over normal tasks because it reduces the number of tasks executed when the handlers do not fire.

Comment: But in this case, the handler is being called twice so the only thing you're saving is about four lines in your playbook code that are going to really confuse someone in the future who is use to the handlers being used in the "fire only once" method.
If you're the only one who will *ever* manage this playbook, then this is probably not a big deal.  If there's a chance that you'll hand this off to a operations team (or better yet retire!) I'd suggest you stick with the two tasks rather than the handler-plus-meta workaround.